# R {caret} trainControl(index = createFolds()) changes default tune parameters?

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret

Have spent a lot of time trying to read the `{caret}` documentation ([here](http://topepo.github.io/caret/training.html#control), [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/caret/docs/trainControl), and [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/caret/docs/createDataPartition)) as well as the `{randomForest}` documentation. Just not understanding what's going on here.

When I run the following code with the parameter `index = createFolds()` in `trainControl`, the values tried of `mtry` are **2**, **28**, and **54**:

```
# Specify fit parameters
set.seed(55555)
fc = trainControl(method = "cv", returnResamp = "all", verboseIter = T, 
                  index = createFolds(fct.og$cover[trn.idx]))

# randomForest Model 1
set.seed(55555)
rf.M1 = train(x = fct.og[trn.idx, -55], 
              y = fct.og[trn.idx, 55], 
              method = "rf", trControl = fc, 
              preProcess = c("nzv", "center", "scale"), 
              verbose = T)
```

However, when I *don't* specify the parameter `index = createFolds()` in `trainControl()`, the values tried of `mtry` are **2**, **12**, and **22**:

```
# Specify fit parameters
set.seed(55555)
fc = trainControl(method = "cv", returnResamp = "all", verboseIter = T)

# randomForest Model 1
set.seed(55555)
rf.M1 = train(x = fct.og[trn.idx, -55], 
              y = fct.og[trn.idx, 55], 
              method = "rf", trControl = fc, 
              preProcess = c("nzv", "center", "scale"), 
              verbose = T)
```

I know by default, the `train(tuneLength = 3)`, so I get why only three values are used. Just not understanding what's going on behind the scenes that causes the values of `mtry` to differ. I'm sure this is user error and I'm missing something obvious in the documentation.

One last question: the model runs *a lot* faster with the parameter `trainControl(index = createFolds())` code. Is there a reason why? It seems the default value of `trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10)` is the same as the default value of `createFolds(k = 10)`?

Comment: Providing a reproducible example and the results of `sessionInfo` will help get your question answered. Are there factors in the predictors? etc. A few ancillary notes though. First, you need to use `returnTrain = TRUE` with `createFolds`. It is running a lot fast since you are training on 10% of the data. Second, there is no `verbose` option for `train`or `randomForest`.

Comment: @topepo Max, thanks so much for the reply. In looking at two `train` objects, with the only difference the `trainControl(index = )` parameter, I see the difference in length for `obj$control$index` and `obj$control$indexOut` (they appear transposed). Also thank you for the tip on `verbose`, though I do get output printed to console during `train()` as if it is on. I will work on an easily run reproducible example, the current one I have is with ~580,000 tuples and 55 attributes. Thank you again, Michael